# MySQL Tables and row count

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a list of tables and their number of rows. I have been using this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase'
```

I am finding this sometimes returns null. What I would like to do is catch this probably doing something similar to

```
IFNULL ( TABLE_ROWS, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ????)
```

Only I'm not sure what I should enter for `????`
how to make it dynamic based on the TABLE_NAME column?.

Edit: Additional information: I found that the 'tables' not displaying are actually views.

Comment: Extended answer for single step, and accurate for InnoDB tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707814/mysql-summarize-all-table-row-counts-in-a-single-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well do

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM YOUR_DATABASE;
```

It always return a column named as `Rows` which is number of rows in that table.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html):

> The TABLE_ROWS column is NULL if the table is in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database.

So, you will propably not need it.

Comment: The table i'm working with is not in the INFORMAITON_SCHEMA database.